# how to insert one letter of the input quote of a user inside the table?

Tags: html, angular

`this is my html code`

```
<section class="insertionCitation">

    <label>Citation:</label>
    <input #citation (keyUp.Enter)='validationCitation(citation.value)'>

</section>
```

`- how do I output 1 letter of the quote of the user in the table below?

- 1 letter in each td
- it only works just if i Hard Code the quote in my .ts :(
  `

```
<section *ngIf = 'citationtPret' >

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

        <thead class= "test1" >

            <tr >
                <td *ngFor='let letter of quote'>{{letter}}</td>
                
            </tr>
           
            <tr>
                <td *ngFor='let letter of quote'>{{letter}}</td>
                
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td *ngFor='let letter of quote'>{{letter}}</td>
                
            </tr>

        </thead>
```

[image: i want the part inside the textbox to be in the table below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put a simple javascript function into your code you could take a string of any size then get the first letter from indexing

e.g.

```
<script>

    function getFirst(){

        quote = document.getElementById("id of the text box"); //get the input box

        letter = quote[0]; // get the first element
        
        return letter;
    }

</script>
```

your html code would probable then look like this

```
<section class="insertionCitation">

<label>Citation:</label>
<input id="citation" (keyUp.Enter)='validationCitation(getFirst())'>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

am not understand your need exactly but if you need to get one lettre from an quote , the code you need is that code

```
let quote=new Array();
function validationCitation(citation){
quote.push(citation.substr(1,1));
}
```